# Is it possible to use the same scaffold to create an album and upload several images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm creating a rails app that allows someone to create an album by adding a title, a description and several pictures. However, I only find on the web a way that needs two controller, one to create the album and another to attach the images on it.

I'm now used to Rails even though I know I still have lots of things to learn.

So far, I managed to allow the user to create something that only allows him to upload to only upload one photo.

So I changed the form part where the file is uploaded, and now, it doesn't save anything...

Here are my files:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @pet, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
    <% if @pet.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@pet.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this album from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @pet.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :description %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :image %><br>
      # added :multiple => true
      <%= f.file_field :image, :multiple => true %>
      <% if f.object.image? %>
          <%= image_tag f.object.image.thumb.url %>
          <%= f.label :remove_image %>
          <%= f.check_box :remove_image %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**pets_controller.rb**

```
class PetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pet, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /pets
  def index
    @pets = Pet.all
  end

  # GET /pets/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /pets/new
  def new
    @pet = Pet.new
  end

  # GET /pets/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /pets
  def create
    @pet = Pet.new(pet_params)

    if @pet.save
      redirect_to @pet, notice: 'Album was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /pets/1
  def update
    if @pet.update(pet_params)
      redirect_to @pet, notice: 'Album was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pets/1
  def destroy
    @pet.destroy
    redirect_to pets_url, notice: 'Album was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pet
      @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def pet_params
      params.require(:pet).permit(:name, :description, :image)
    end
end
```

So my summed up question is the following: is there a simple way to allow my form to save multiple images inside an array where it would be easy to show them up?

Thank you in advance